# iframe not loading HTML Page I want to perform onClick operation on it but instead HTML is working on its own

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

[image]

The question I have is I don't want my HTML pages to work in the iframe instead want them to just display and when someone click on them a new page gets open.

Right now Top Row Middle Iframe has an audio and it is being played on clicking
similarly in Bottom row first iframe has a dropdown which is working but I want if anyone clicks anywhere it should open a corresponding page

pointer-events none is disabling the onclick event as well.

Comment: Check network tab, maybe it's a 404 not found or 403 denied?

Comment: Please see [ask].  If you have a second question, please create a new question for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must add some sort of a container over the iframe to block any interactions with the iframe. Additionally, that container must be bound to a mouse click event that would take you to the page displayed in the iframe.

Here is a working example:

```js
// Here is an event listner to bind a click event to the container
// that covers the iframe.
// All it does is take you to the page that the iframe is displaying
document.getElementById("cover-iframe").addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.location.href = 'test.html'
})
```

```css
/* Set the size of this container (width, height)
to change the size of the iframe */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50rem;
}

.iframe {
  width: 100%;
}

/* This is to make the container cover the iframe */
#cover-iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This container is to hold the iframe and the container that will cover the iframe  -->
  <div class="container">
    <!-- "test.html" can be changed to the page you want to display -->
    <iframe src="test.html" frameborder="1" class="iframe"></iframe>
    <span id="cover-iframe"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I added comments to the code above to make it self explanatory.

Comment: @TabishTanseef You're welcome.